# jQuery and regular javascript: prevent jQUery onclick from firing base on parent result

Tags: jquery, onclick, form-submit, onclicklistener

I have some simple HTML:

```
    <input type="submit" value="Save" onclick="return isAbleToSubmit();" id="testSubmit" class="alertWhenDone"/>
function isAbleToSubmit() {
    return confirm ("Do you want to continue?");
}
```

I than have jQuery code:

```
$(".alertWhenDone").click(function (event) {
   alert ("i am done");
}
```

I only want alert when done to be call if they choose yes on confirmation. 
What is the best way to do this?

Note that I have it separate out cause I want all class with `alertWhenDone` to have the function to show processing link msg.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `data-*` attribute and store the `prompt` strings in them. try this:

```
<input type="submit" value="Save" data-confirm="Do you want to continue?" id="testSubmit" class="alertWhenDone"/>
```

```
$("input[type=submit]").click(function (event) {
   if (confirm ($(this).data('confirm'))) {
        alert ("i am done");
   }
})
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/y62eD/)

Comment: sorry isAbleToSubmit only applies to some certain submit button not all.What I mean is all submit will have alert ("i am done") but different submit id (like on different page) will have differnt prompt...

Comment: @user578635 you can use `data-` attribute and store the prompt strings in them.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the onClick event from your input and do:

```
$(function(){

 $('#testSubmit').click(function(){
    $return = confirm ("Do you want to continue?");
    if ($return == true){
        if ( $(this).hasClass('alertWhenDone') == true){
            //doStuff
            alert('done');                
        }
    }
 })        
})
```

[example](http://jsfiddle.net/EmpbY/)